# Clean install with home folder and multiple users

Tags: installation, home-directory

I had reformatted my system (unfortunately an update failed) and had my home folder on a separate partition. Thankfully I still have all of my users files (in their respective folders), but there was no option to use this on install (since my update had failed...).

How can I recreate the old users with their previous home directories?

*(Are there problems with user permissions with just dragging and dropping the entire contents of folders?)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup the partitions to have home set to /dev/sdb1 (for example) during setup. There is an option for "Something else" during install at the hard drive section. As long as you create the users in the same order, it **should** do permissions correctly (no promises, of course).

I am not 100% on just copy and pasting the files and permissions in say nautilus, but you can always run `sudo chown <user>:<user> -R /home/<user>` after you copy it to set the folder to the correct owner. That should set everything correctly.